# Meteor.loginWithPassword: Amend verification

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using accounts-password and `Meteor.loginWithPassword` to authenticate a user. I want to prevent the user from being able to login unless the email address is verified.

Currently I do this using a `Meteor.method` and a callback. The callback will only trigger the call to `Meteor.loginWithPassword()` if the relevant user has a verified email address and trigger the current form to display a validation error. if not. However a tech-savvy user can still trigger `Meteor.loginWithPassword()` directly in the console. Is there a best practice way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent logins for users with an email address which has not been verified by using **[`accountsServer.validateLoginAttempt(func)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt)**, for example:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt) {
    var user = attempt.user;
    if (!user.emails[0].verified) throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'E-Mail address not verified.');
    return true;
  });
}
```

If you return `false` or throw an exception, the login will be aborted.

Comment: Its better to add this code under `server` directory and no in client and wrapping it under `if (Meteor.isServer) {`